# how to select all columns from all tables with it's max values from 1 schema in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a schema with around 300 tables, and need to find max value of each columns of each table, lets assume i have table "Person" with columns: "name", "surname", "passport_number" and table "Person_phone" with columns: "phone_number", "years_of_using", result should be like that:

| table | column | max_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Person | name | Martisj |
| Person | surname | Khusina |
| Person | passport_number | 999999234989 |
| Person_phone | phone_number | +48930290320 |
| Person_phone | years_of_using | 10 |

Comment: Does this include every data type? If so you may be very disappointed and only want to get those max values for certain types and perhaps different output columns for each type.
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Supported_data_types.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21446650/2067753 has a relevant script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code for a [procedure](https://gist.github.com/damjad/a82cc962384817f93ec319e1c427b109) that does this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE max_of_all_columns(schema_name TEXT)
AS
$$
DECLARE
  ro    RECORD;
  max_r RECORD;
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_xyz;
  CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_xyz
  (
    table_name  VARCHAR(100),
    column_name VARCHAR(100),
    max_val     TEXT
  );
  
  FOR ro IN SELECT
              QUOTE_IDENT(table_name) :: VARCHAR                                 AS table_name,
              QUOTE_IDENT(column_name) :: VARCHAR                                AS column_name,
              'SELECT MAX(' || QUOTE_IDENT(column_name) || ') :: TEXT AS max_val FROM ' || QUOTE_IDENT(table_catalog) ||
              '.' || QUOTE_IDENT(table_schema) || '.' || QUOTE_IDENT(table_name) AS max_query
  FROM
    information_schema.columns c
  WHERE
    table_schema = schema_name AND data_type IN (
                                                 -- add more types if necessary
                                                 'bigint',
                                                 'character',
                                                 'character varying',
                                                 'date',
                                                 'double precision',
                                                 'integer',
                                                 'numeric',
                                                 'real',
                                                 'smallint',
                                                 'timestamp without time zone'
    )
    LOOP
      EXECUTE ro.max_query INTO max_r;
      INSERT INTO tmp_xyz(table_name, column_name, max_val)
      VALUES (ro.table_name, ro.column_name, max_r.max_val);
    END LOOP;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Let's create some test tables.

```
-- create schema for testing.
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS trash;

-- add test tables. 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS trash.tmp_xyz;
CREATE TABLE trash.tmp_xyz AS
SELECT 1::INT AS abc, 45::INT AS xyz UNION ALL SELECT 2::INT AS abc, 24::INT AS xyz;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS trash.tmp_abc;
CREATE TABLE trash.tmp_abc AS
SELECT 1::INT AS abc, 'Maartin'::VARCHAR AS xyz_varchar UNION ALL SELECT 2::INT AS abc, 'Khusia'::VARCHAR AS xyz_varchar;
```

Let's now execute the procedure.

```
CALL max_of_all_columns('trash');
SELECT * FROM tmp_xyz;
```

The result is as follows:

```
|table_name|column_name|max_val|
+----------+-----------+-------+
|tmp_abc   |abc        |2      |
|tmp_abc   |xyz_varchar|Maartin|
|tmp_xyz   |abc        |2      |
|tmp_xyz   |xyz        |45     |
+----------+-----------+-------+
```